# Projected Data in bandwidth

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get a projected data in the bottom of bandwidth.(refer to attached picture) I can't find Java API to get projected data. If you provide me a sample code, it will be appreciated. Thank you
[image: bandwidth graph]

Answer (score 0):

The baremetal servers and virtual guests have a property called "projectedPublicBandwidthUsage", this property contains the value you are looking for.

you can use the getObject method to get it using a object mask like this:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$BAREMETALID/getObject?objectMask=mask[projectedPublicBandwidthUsage]
```

or you can use these methods:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getProjectedPublicBandwidthUsage

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getProjectedPublicBandwidthUsage

The result is displayed in GB, if you want to display as in the portal make sure you are converting the data to MB

Regards